# Best way to handle relationships to objects I cannot create look ups for?

Tags: administration, lookup, relationships, data-category

I have an object and it needs to have a 1 - many reference to the Data Category used in knowledge base.  We have a requirement to be able to configure which data categories show up on a given page.

So what is the best way to actually have the reference exists?  The only real option I can think of is have a Multi-select pick-list.  Of course, if the data categories are ever changed, this will start breaking things.

As a second part that fits under the same topic...  What is the best way to add a record type or permission set reference to an Object?

Comment: multiselect pick-list wont have 1-many effect, I believe. :(
If you have 1-many relationship configured you could just use related list or have I missed something in the question?

Comment: What i meant is MyObject__c would have a multi-select picklist where each value would represent the name of a data category.  That way you could "relate" multiple data categories to a single MyObject.

Comment: Ok. Then I understood your question RIGHT. In that case, multi select pick is not the best bet. Like I mentioned in my previous comment your best bet is to use `related list`, **if** you have lookup of `myobject__c` in `data category`.

Comment: I wasn't aware that I could add a lookup to `Data Categories`... Are you sure thats possible?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm not sure about that. I need to search that myself whether you can add custom fields, like lookup, to data category (article) or not.

Comment: Yes, you can. I just tested it by creating a new article type and adding a lookup relationship (to any SObject) . Added an answer in detail. Thanks for this question it helped me research on this. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to create a **related list** of `Data categories` (articles) on `MyObject__c`.

Steps to create a lookup of `MyObject__c` on `Article`.

1. Create / Edit an existing article type
2. When you create an Article type, SF would create an object with name of the article type.
3. Now as shown below would appear
   [image]
4. Clicke `New`, a generic SF new field page will open
5. Select `Lookup` relationship
6. Select the `MyObject__c` from the `Related To` dropdown.

And that's it.

Comment: Sooo, I understand where your going but thats not quite what I'm looking for.  We are already using Article types to represent a different part of our model (FAQ, Process, Tutorial, etc).  We use data categories to represent different areas of our KB.  For example, we may have a data category that is used to mark everything under our FooBar service.  Thus I'm trying to figure out how I can create a relation that will allow me to query all article types of a given data query, dynamically off the object relationships we set up.  Hope that is clear